# unable to select the Id in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore, under user Employee collection i want to delete a particular employee using id. my code is

```
export const employeeSave = ({
    name,
    phone,
    shift,
    uid
}) => {
    const {
        currentUser
    } = firebase.auth();
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('employees').doc(uid).update({
            name,
            phone,
            shift
        }).then(() => {
            dispatch({
                type: EMPLOYEE_SAVE_SUCCESS
            });
            Actions.employeeList({
                type: 'reset'
            });
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Please  wrap your code in the code quotas `` or  use this help in order to able to read && understand your codes :https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score 0):

`.update` expects an object, or key/value pairs. So try:

```
.update({
 name: "joe",
 phone: "123-234-5567",
 shift: "night"
})
```

Comment: thank you very much for reply 
for delete a selected employee, i m using this code
export const employeeDelete = ({ uid }) => {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('employees').doc(uid)
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        Actions.employeeList({ type: 'reset' });
      });
but it is throwing an error
'relativePath.split is not a function' 
please help me

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you just want to call delete

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).collection('employees').doc(uid).delete()
```

see here for more https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: Thank for reply , I did same as you mention then it is throwing this error

'relativePath.split is not a function'

please help

Comment: you need to get better at javascript. this isnt a firebase issue.